# How to tie-out with VBA, Oracle, and Excel using INDEX & MATCH functions?

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, indexing

I am trying to create a program using VBA that queries my oracle database data (in this case pipelines) against a spreadsheet and produces an output of the tie-out on the same workbook (but on another sheet). I would like to use the INDEX and MATCH functions on the tie-out page but have trouble figuring it out. Here is what I have so far (graphical representation below) and here are my questions:

**WHAT I HAVE:**
I have 4 tabs on my workbook:
1. Spreadsheet Data
2. Instructions (where user is prompted for Pipeline, end/start dates for the query)
3. Database output data (the VBA script will pull up the data from Oracle database)
4. Tie out data tab (this is where I have trouble)

**QUESTIONS:**
1) How to make the tie out page, using INDEX and MATCH, lookup values from my oracle database sheet and my spreadsheet?
2) Instead of PROMPTING  the user for the pipeline, how may I create a drop down box so that the user selects ONE pipeline? This will reduce any user input errors (such as spelling, and etc).

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

MY CODE:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
'user is prompted for dates and pipeline name
'click button will prompt query

Dim cnnObject As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsObject As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strGPOTSConnectionString As String
'this will remove old sql data upon new query

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Pipeline As String
Dim DateStart As Date
Dim DateEnd As Date
Dim strQuery As String

Sub Say(s As String)
    Debug.Print s
End Sub

Sub ClickButton2()

    Debug.Print ("Button has been clicked")

    'KGK
    Set ws = Worksheets("ZaiNet Data")
    ws.UsedRange.Clear '' remove results of previous query if any
    'this will fill in null values in query as "data not available"

    Pipeline = InputBox("Enter PipeLine", "My Application", "Default Value")
    DateStart = InputBox("Enter Start Date", "My Application", DateTime.Date)
    DateEnd = InputBox("Enter End Date", "My Application", DateTime.Date + 1)

    Range("B1").Value = Pipeline
    Range("B2").Value = DateStart
    Range("B3").Value = DateEnd

    'KGK:  call to function to populate the IN() part of the SQL statement
    Dim dtInDate As String
    dtInDate = GetIN(DateStart, DateEnd)

    Debug.Print (" ")

    'strQuery = "select pipelineflow.lciid lciid, ldate, volume, capacity, status, " & _
        "pipeline, station, stationname, drn, state, county, owneroperator, companycode, " & _
        "pointcode, pointtypeind, flowdirection, pointname, facilitytype, pointlocator, " & _
        "pidgridcode from pipelineflow, pipelineproperties " & _
        "where pipelineflow.lciid = pipelineproperties.lciid " & _
        "and pipelineflow.audit_active = 1 " & _
        "and pipelineproperties.audit_active =1 " & _
        "and pipelineflow.ldate >= '" & Format(DateStart, "m/d/yyyy") & "' and pipelineflow.ldate < '" & Format(DateEnd, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "' " & _
        "and pipelineproperties.pipeline = '" & Pipeline & "' "

    strQuery = "select pipelineflow.lciid lciid, ldate, volume, capacity, status, " & _
        "pipeline, station, stationname, drn, state, county, owneroperator, companycode, " & _
        "pointcode, pointtypeind, flowdirection, pointname, facilitytype, pointlocator, " & _
        "pidgridcode from pipelineflow, pipelineproperties " & _
        "where pipelineflow.lciid = pipelineproperties.lciid " & _
        "and pipelineflow.audit_active = 1 " & _
        "and pipelineproperties.audit_active =1 " & _
        "and pipelineflow.ldate " & dtInDate & _
        "and pipelineproperties.pipeline = '" & Pipeline & "' "

    'KGK:  modify strQuery

    'Debug.Print (strQuery)

    Call PullZaiNetData(strQuery)

    Call TieOut

End Sub

Sub PullZaiNetData2(ByVal strQry As String)

    Set cnnObject = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rsObject = New ADODB.Recordset

    strGPOTSConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; SERVER=XXX; PWD=XXX; UID=XXX"


    cnnObject.Open strGPOTSConnectionString

    'this will give a record count and will help to verify values

    'rsObject.Open strQry, cnnObject, adOpenStatic
    'Say rsObject.RecordCount & " records"
    'If rsObject.RecordCount = 0 Then
    '    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "DATA NOT AVAILABLE"
    'Else
    '    ws.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsObject
    'End If

    rsObject.Open strQry, cnnObject, adOpenStatic
    Worksheets("ZaiNet Data").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsObject


    rsObject.Close
    cnnObject.Close

    Set rsObject = Nothing
    Set cnnObject = Nothing

End Sub

Sub TieOut()
    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            Worksheets("TieOut").Cells(i, j).Value = "'=INDEX('database data for all dates '!$A$1:$U$314,MATCH(AH$4&TEXT($B8,""m/dd/yyyy""),'database data for all dates '!$C$1:$C$314,0),4)"
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function GetIN(ByVal startDate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date) As String

    Dim arrDates() As Date
    Dim currentDate As Variant
    Dim dateInterval As Integer
    Dim strIN As String
    Dim i As Integer

    dateInterval = DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate)
    dateInterval = dateInterval + 1
    ReDim arrDates(1 To dateInterval)

    For i = 1 To dateInterval
        arrDates(i) = DateAdd("d", i - 1, startDate)
    Next i

    'debug loop

    'For i = 1 To dateInterval
    '    Debug.Print ("i: " & i & ", date: " & arrDates(i))
    'Next i

    'Convert the date array to string

    strIN = " IN("

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrDates)
        strIN = strIN & "'" & CStr(Format(arrDates(i), "m/d/yyyy")) & "'"
        If i < UBound(arrDates) Then
            strIN = strIN & ", "
        End If
    Next

    strIN = strIN & ") "

    'debug statement
    'Debug.Print (strIN)

    GetIN = strIN

End Function
```

Comment: re: creating the dropdown box. Where do the pipeline names come from: hardcoded on the worksheet or read from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Q1. It looks like you're trying to do some kind of date matching, but without seeing the actual sheet, it's a little hard to provide an exact formula.

A few thoughts though:

- You probably already knew this,
  but you will need to change Cell(i,
  j).Value to Cell(i, j).Formula and
  get rid of the apostrophe before
  "=INDEX" if you want your formula to
  actually work.
- In your MATCH function, you are
  searching for AH$4 &
  TEXT($B8,""m/dd/yyyy"". This looks a
  little suspicious to me. What is in
  cell AH$4? Does Oracle spit out some
  kind of weird prefix before dates? If
  you just had plain dates in your
  cells, you wouldn't need to worry
  about the format (you could get rid
  of TEXT and just do a pure
  comparison). Excel stores dates as a
  "serial" number. Also, check out the
  help on DATEVALUE. That might help
  you to get things converted over to
  pure dates.
- Just a general word of advice. Get
  your MATCH expression working first.
  Then try inserting the MATCH
  expression into the INDEX expression.
  This will help you to isolate your
  exact problem.

Q2. It looks like you have the list of pipelines already on your sheet, so you can create a validation that will guarantee that the user only selects a legitimate pipeline.

- Assign a name to your list of
  pipelines. You do this by selecting
  your list of pipelines, clicking
  Define Name from the Formulas tab of
  the ribbon, then entering a name.
- Choose a cell on the worksheet for
  the user to select a pipeline.
- Click Data Validation on the Data tab
  of the ribbon.
- For Allow, choose List.
- For Source, type an equal sign
  followed by the name you assigned for
  your list of pipelines. So, if your
  name was Pipelines, you would enter
  =Pipelines.

Now, when the user clicks on that cell, only the Pipelines will appear in it.